# Repeat question until correctly given in R

Tags: r, loops, prompt

I'm trying to repeat a prompt until the correct answer is given.

Something like "Please write a number."

I have so far

```
number <- as.numeric(readline(prompt = "Write a number:"))
```

I want it so that if the input is anything but a number, then it will repeat the question until a number is given.

My train of thought is to use a `repeat` loop and `tryCatch` until it is true.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your original code above, how about this:

```
number <- function(){
  x <- NA
  while(is.na(x)){
    x <- as.numeric(readline(prompt = "Write a number:"))
  }
}
number()
```

This will print a warning if a non-numeric character is the input.  To turn those off, you could add a couple of lines to the function:

```
number <- function(print_warnings=FALSE){
  ## turn off global warnings if print_warnings is FALSE
  if(!print_warnings)options(warn=-1)
  x <- NA
  while(is.na(x)){
    x <- as.numeric(readline(prompt = "Write a number:"))
  }
  ## turn global warnings back on 
  options(warn=0)
}
number()
```

Note, that this turns off warnings globally, but turns them back on at the end.

Comment: Thanks, this works! Now, how would you be able to store 'x' once the condition is true?

Comment: It's not exactly best practices, but you cold use `x <<- x` to assign x to the global environment outside of the function, right after the end of the while loop.  Alternatively, you could just have the function return `x` and assign the output of the function to an object.  You can have the function return `x` by just printing `x` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
number <- "whatever"
while(is.na(number)|!is.numeric(number))
  number <- as.numeric(readline(prompt = "Write a number:"))
```

Of course you could have many warnings, in order to suppress them use the below:

```
number <- "whatever"
options(warn=-1)
while(is.na(number)|!is.numeric(number)) {
  number <- as.numeric(readline(prompt = "Write a number:"))
}
options(warn=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `repeat`

```
number <- function(){
 
  repeat({
    x <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(readline(prompt = "Write a number:")))
    
    if(!is.na(x)) break
    x
    }
    
    )
    x
  
}
```

-testing

```
n1 <- number()
#Write a number:'a'
#Write a number:'5'
#Write a number:5
n1
#[1] 5
```